# How to polyfill element's methods?

Tags: javascript, polyfills

Many times I find that I need methods that are not so widespread among browsers. I know I don't need a polyfill to solve this everytime but I think they are usefull and I'd like to know the steps to implement them.

In this case, i'd like to polyfill the `element.closest()` method, but this is just an example. Notice my question here is not how to polyfill that method in particular but how to add that method to every new element from querySelector.

Obviously the first step is cheking for support:

```
if(!document.querySelector("body").closest){
  //Now that we know the method is not available,
  //we should modify the global methods of every new selection
  //so that it includes the new method.
}
function closest(property, value){
  while (x = x.parentElement) { 
    if (x[property] == value) return x;
  }
  return null;
}
```

My question is about how to connect this to blocks. Could you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so you have your polyfill function ready. Now, you need to inject it to the node object.

```
Node.prototype.closest = closest;
```

To check if it is working:

```
if (typeof Node.prototype.closest == "undefined") {
  Node.prototype.closest = function () {
    console.log("Hi");
  }
}
```

If you wanna do this to the elements, you need to use `HTMLElement` object:

```
if (typeof HTMLElement.prototype.closest == "undefined") {
  HTMLElement.prototype.closest = function () {
    console.log("Hi");
  }
}
```

Then you can call:

```
document.closest();
a = document.querySelector("#one-element-with-id");
a.closest();
```

Comment: What is the difference between HTMLElement and Node? Also, how can I get all those native objects like HTMLElement, Node, DOMTokenList and stuff like that? (this is not usually on books about js)

Comment: You can have a look at the [Web API Interfaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) at the Mozilla Developers Network! @Vandervals. They are classes and subclasses of the same class! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has so-called "prototypal inheritance model".

You could add to Element object your `closest` method if it doesn't have it itself.

```
if (typeof(Element.prototype.closest == 'undefined')) {
  Element.prototype.closest = function(property, value) {
    var x = this;
    while (x = x.parentElement) { 
      if (x[property] == value) {
        return this;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Usage of you closest method will be:

`document.querySelector('#some-id').closest('href', 'http://google.com');`

You could use `Element` for dealing with `Document` elements such as `HTMLElement` and `SVGElement`. `HTMLElement` is more specific.

**UPD**

> The following interfaces all inherit from Node its methods and
>   properties: Document, Element, CharacterData (which Text, Comment, and
>   CDATASection inherit), ProcessingInstruction, DocumentFragment,
>   DocumentType, Notation, Entity, EntityReference
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node
>
> The Element interface represents an object of a Document. This
>   interface describes methods and properties common to all kinds of
>   elements. Specific behaviors are described in interfaces which inherit
>   from Element but add additional functionality. For example, the
>   HTMLElement interface is the base interface for HTML elements, while
>   the SVGElement interface is the basis for all SVG elements.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element
>
> The HTMLElement interface represents any HTML element. Some elements
>   directly implement this interface, others implement it via an
>   interface that inherits it.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement

**UPD2**

Code of your `closest` was incorrect. I fixed it.

There is a full snippet you could try.

```js
if (typeof(Element.prototype.closest == 'undefined')) {
  Element.prototype.closest = function(property, value) {
    var x = this;
    while (x = x.parentElement) { 
      if (x[property] == value) {
        return this;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  var a = document.querySelector('#my-image').closest('href', 'http://google.com/');
  console.log(a);
  alert(a);
});
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com/"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" id="my-image" width="350" height="150"></a>
```

Comment: what is de difference between adding that to Element or to Node?

Comment: @Vandervals `Node` is a "parent" of Element `class` and more wider. Updated my answer.

Comment: @Vandervals You could use `Element` for dealing with `Document` elements such as `HTMLElement` and `SVGElement`. `HTMLElement` is more specific.